# cudaMemcpy throwing error during simple copy

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

Below is a small piece of code that copies 4 elements from an array to the GPU. I really dont understand why cudaMemcpy is throwing an error in this case. Please help

```
int size = 5;
float *a = (float*)malloc(size * sizeof(float));
a[0] = 1.0;
a[1] = 2.0;
a[2] = 3.0;
a[3] = 4.0;
a[4] = 5.0;

float *g;
cudaMalloc((void**)g, 4 * sizeof(float));
float *tem = a+2;
cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpy(g,a,4 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if(err !=0){
    printf("Cudamemcpy threw error\n");
    getchar();  
}
```

Comment: What error is it throwing, exactly? `cudaGetErrorString` will parse the return status of any runtime API function into a human readable string.

Comment: I see that you are allocating an array of size 4 floats on the GPU and copying an array of size 5 floats to it.

Comment: @Jay: the memory copy is only copying `4*sizeof(float)` bytes to the array. It is not a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are missing an ampersand:

`cudaMalloc((void**)&g, 4 * sizeof(float));`